# Compact graph-vizualization using pydot

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, graphviz, graph-visualization, pydot

I would like to visualize a "linear" directed graph with the layout like that:

[image: compact visualization]

All the in- and out-degrees are 1 (except the first and last, of course). The length of the labels are different, so I can't calculate easily, how many nodes will fit in one row or the other. The code I have so far is this.

```py
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import to_pydot

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node("XYZ 1.0")
for i in range(1, 20):
    G.add_node(f'XYZ 1.{i}', style='filled', fillcolor='skyblue')
    G.add_edge(f'XYZ 1.{i-1}', f'XYZ 1.{i}')

# set defaults
G.graph['graph'] = {'rankdir': 'LR'}
G.graph['node'] = {'shape': 'rectangle'}
G.graph['edges'] = {'arrowsize': '4.0'}

pydt = to_pydot(G)
prog = 'dot'
file_name = f'nx_graph_{prog}.png'
pydt.write(file_name, prog=prog, format="png")
```

So far I use `networkx` in a project that needs to be run in a Python docker container, so I would like to use `pydot` and `Networkx`, if it is possible.

In some of the graphviz programs I can set coordinates if I understand correctly, but for setting coordinates I should know the widths of the boxes to avoid overlapping boxes.

Comment: I cannot speak to pydot or networkx, but 'dot -Tdot' will give widths and heights.  Remember that 'neato -n' is the program that accepts explicit positions ('pos' values).  (see https://www.graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords)

Comment: @sroush Thanks, I used that information in my answer. It was essential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way to do this with pydot. We can create a dot file with the coordinates with the `write_dot` function. Reading it back, we can get the coordinates that `dot` program created (and also the widths, heights). We can somehow calculate the new coordinates and modify them in the `networkx` Digraph. Converting again to `pydot.Dot` object, and at the end, we can use `neato` with the `-n` option to create the graph, that way we use the coordinates we have set. A working code can be seen below.

```py
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import to_pydot
import pydot
from typing import List

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(0, label="XYZ 1.0")
for i in range(1, 20):
    G.add_node(i, label=f'XYZ 1.{i}')
    G.add_edge(i - 1, i)

# set defaults
G.graph['graph'] = {'rankdir': 'LR'}
G.graph['node'] = {'shape': 'rectangle'}
G.graph['edges'] = {'arrowsize': '4.0'}

pydt = to_pydot(G)
dot_data = pydt.create_dot()

pydt2 = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.decode('utf-8'))[0]


def get_position(node):
    pydot_node = pydt2.get_node(str(node))[0]
    return [float(i) for i in pydot_node.get_attributes().get("pos")[1:-1].split(',')]


def fix_position(position: List, w: float = 1000, shift: float = 80):
    x_orig, y_orig = position
    n = int(x_orig / w)
    y = y_orig - n * shift
    remain_x = x_orig - n * w
    if n % 2 == 0:
        x = remain_x
    else:
        x = w - remain_x
    return x, y


def refresh_coordinates_using_x():
    for node in G.nodes:
        position = get_position(node)
        x, y = fix_position(position)
        pos = f'"{x},{y}!"'
        G.nodes[node]['pos'] = pos


refresh_coordinates_using_x()

pydt3 = to_pydot(G)
file_name = f'nx_graph_neato.png'
pydt3.write(file_name, prog=["neato", "-n"], format="png")
```

If you want to calculate the position of the nodes based on the widths, you need to know, that while the coordinates are in points, the widths are in inches. 1 inch is 72 points.

The result will be similar to this one.

[image]